# Contract Call has been reverted by the EVM with the reason: 'execution aborted (timeout = 5s)'

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j

I defined an array of objects in the Ethereum smart contract. An object is a structure that is inserted into the array every time a function is called.When 80,000 data is inserted, it takes a long time, estimated at 25 hours...When traversing the array filter, directly reported timeout.The geth client used
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The EVM is ineffective for working with large arrays. Use mapping.
Design your contract to avoid iterative processing of large arrays

Comment: Since I am doing an analysis and research on the performance of block chain storage and query of large amount of data, I need to use a set to store data. Due to the data format, I may not be able to construct the mapping

Comment: Perhaps you will be interested in an article on comparing the use of an array and mapping in smart contracts (in Russian) -https://habr.com/ru/company/raiffeisenbank/blog/354122/

Answer (score 2):

I find it very unnecessary to use an array and traverse over it.If you really want to do something like this, just don't use loop

**Question 1: Why don't use loops?**

**Answer**: *Because Transaction fee will increase with each loop and will cost use alot of money. Plus it's the slowest method for searching method*

**Question 2: Then what is other option to do code this function?**

**Answer**: *Store each id in mapping(address=>uint256[]). It will cost you alot less and it'll be far more efficient also.*

Comment: Since I am doing an analysis and research on the performance of block chain storage and query of large amount of data, I need to use a set to store data. Due to the data format, I may not be able to construct the mapping